# List of acronyms: repetition

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

It is not exactly a LateX question but LateX users might have an interesting opinion on the question below. In a text I am working on, a few acronyms are used. Let's take the following example: ABCD for Arbitrarily Boring Concept of Dust. The text in question sometimes uses "Arbitrarily Boring Concept of Dust" (ABDC), sometimes "Boring Concept of Dust" (BCD) and sometimes "Concept of Dust" (CD). The corresponding list of acronyms could then have the three entries ABCD, BCD and CD. However, would it be acceptable to go for a more compact list where these three acronyms are merged together? Something like

```
\nomenclature{[A](B)CD}{[A]rbitrarily (B)oring Concept of Dust}
```

or

```
\nomenclature{[A](B)CD}{[Arbitrarily] (Boring) Concept of Dust}
```

Comment: IMO, final text should show: `ABCD, BCD, CD  : [A]rbitrarily (B)oring Concept of Dust`

Comment: `[[A]B]CD: [[Arbitrarily] Boring] Concept of Dust` feels more appropriate to me, but if you have a large list and I'm looking up `CD` this is really unhelpful.  If the list is short enough to be read in its entirety then `ABCD: Arbitrarily Boring [...]` probably implies the meaning of `CD` already without adding any potentially ambiguous notation.

Comment: @anis interesting idea!

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks! The list in question is fairly short and can be read in its entirety. All suggestions are acceptable I believe!

Comment: @pluton you're probably right this is a good place to ask for opinions, but I'm not sure if there's a question that can be answered on-topic here?

Comment: @DaiBowen I am happy to delete the question if it is decided to do so.